# iGraph in Python: Relation between a VertexDendrogram object and VertexClustering object

Tags: python, igraph, hierarchical-clustering

Using iGraph's community detection function community_fastgreedy() in Python, I got a VertexDendrogram object, let's call it V. Then using V.as_clustering() I got a VertexClustering object from the dendrogram. I know that the communities are clustered so that modularity is maximized, but I think the dendogram object keeps merging all the way, so it's tough to see the communities on the dendrogram.

My question is: How does the output for the V.as_clustering() correspond to distance between the communities in the dendrogram?

In other words, The communities each come with a representative number ( Community [0], Community [2] for example), so how does the that number correspond to position on the dendrogram? Are community 0 and Community 1 adjacent to each other when the dendrogram is merged up to the level that maximizes modularity, and is community 12 farther from community 0 than 3 is?

If not, then how is the order (the numbers for each community) of the output decided by the as_clustering function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an algorithm in igraph produces a `VertexDendrogram`, it may optionally produce a "hint" as well that tells us where to cut the dendrogram (i.e. after how many merges) to obtain a `VertexClustering` that is in some sense optimal. For instance, the `VertexDendrogram` produced by `community_fastgreedy()` proposes that the dendrogram should be cut at the point where the modularity is maximized. Running `as_clustering()` on a `VertexDendrogram` simply uses the hint produced by the clustering algorithm to flatten the dendrogram into a clustering, but you may override this by specifying the desired number of clusters as an argument to `as_clustering()`.

As for the "distance" between two communities: it's a complicated thing because most community detection methods don't give you that information. They simply produce a sequence of merges from individual vertices up to a mega-community encapsulating everyone, and there is no "distance" information encoded in the dendrogram; in other words, the branches of the dendrogram have no "length". The best you can do is probably to go back to your graph and check the edge density between the communities; this could be a good indication of closeness. For example:

```
cl = g.community_fastgreedy().as_clustering()
comm1 = cl[0]
comm2 = cl[1]
edges_between = g.es.select(_between=(comm1, comm2))
print 2.0 * len(edges_between) / len(comm1) * len(comm2)
```

If your graph is directed, use a multiplier of 1.0 instead of 2.0 in the last line.

Comment: Ok, I get this now, so just to be sure, when a dendrogram is cut by as_clustering() using that hint, the output community numbers are representative of their position on the dendrogram cut using the hint. So are community [0] and community [1] are closest to each other on one end of the dendrogram, while let's say 12 and 13 are close to each other, but far from 0 and 1?

Comment: No, the community numbers are not representative of anything - their only meaning is that two vertices are in the same community if and only if their community indices are the same.